# Where should I use addChild?

Tags: actionscript-3

When I use as3, I need to create classes that extend "Sprite" all the time. And I always wonder where to use the addChild method : inside the class itself (in the constructor for example), or in the external class calling the constructor.

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is both.

The sprite class is a container, if the goal of your class is a container, you can use addChild outside of your constructor.

If you want to create UI object ready to good with multiple instances of the same object, create a class with addChild in constructor or any other class method.